# GROUP BY agrupando os dados de outra coluna em uma outra coluna

Tags: php, mysql, query, mariadb

tudo bem? preciso de uma ajuda, vou explicar abaixo o que estou fazendo e o que preciso:

Estou desenvolvendo para uma agência de publicidade digital um sistema de e-mail automático que contém todas as campanhas e formatos que um atendimento possua no ar do determinado mês por exemplo, porém, preciso agrupar os formatos em uma única campanha.

Abaixo como os valores vem:

CAMPANHA X

FORMATO 1

CAMPANHA X

FORMATO 2

CAMPANHA X

FORMATO 3

O que preciso:

CAMPANHA X

FORMATO 1

FORMATO 2

FORMATO 3

Como posso fazer isso no SQL?

Comment: Poste as estruturas de suas tabelas que, dependendo disso, pode ser algo extremamente simples. Pode ser: CAMPANHA X FORMATO 1 FORMATO 2 FORMATO 3?

Comment: SQL não resolve , isto tem de ser resolvido na camada de exibição.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT campanha, formato FROM tabela GROUP BY campanha
```

Isso é o que da pra responder pela quantidade de informações que você passou. Tente elaborar melhor a questão ou colocar a estrutura da sua tabela. E a questão nao parece relacionada a php.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pessoal, resolví de uma forma diferente... fiz um GROUP_CONCAT nos campos que precisava e no final usei GROUP BY campanha, e após isso fiz um for com todas as informações que precisava, e deu certo!